# Alea.cubase gpu programming in F#

Tags: f#, aleagpu

While running one piece of code using Alea.cuBase I am getting a **type initialization exception**

```
let worker = Engine.workers.DefaultWorker
```

> `System.TypeInitializationException` was unhandled
>   Message: The type initializer for `'Worker'` threw an exception.

I am using

- visual studio 2012
- .Net frame work 4.0
- F# 3.1

Another piece of code I tried and got the same error at,

```
useprogram = template |> Compiler.loadWorker.Default
```

I started with trial version of **Alea.cuBase 1.3.914**.

Guide me how to fix this..

Comment: Are you able to follow the [Getting Started instructions](http://www.aleacubase.com/manual/1_3_914/getting_started.html)?

Comment: yes i could follow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got resolved.
My pc was having graphics card quadro fx 1800.
Because Alea cuBase support fermi or higher architecture.
When I tried with k4000 I could run the same program.